# Как написать функцию?

Tags: javascript, json

Требуется выполнить задание:

> напишите код функции func(x), возвращающей JSON в виде корректной строки (являющейся результатом применения функции JSON.stringify к объекту); у исходного объекта должно быть свойство love со строковым значением javascript и свойство year с числовым значением 2020 и свойство arg со значением x.

пробую, вариант ниже, не совсем пойму, куда function func(x) вставить?

```
const a = 
{  love: 'javascript',  year: 2020,  avg: 'x', full()
{
    return JSON.stringify(this.love + this.year + this.avg);  
}
}
  console.log(a.full())
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, идем по заданию

> напишите код функции func(x)

```js
function func(x)
{
    // ...
}
```

> возвращающей JSON в виде корректной строки (являющейся результатом применения функции JSON.stringify к объекту)

```js
function func(x)
{
    return JSON.stringify(...);
}
```

> у исходного объекта должно быть свойство love со строковым значением javascript и свойство year с числовым значением 2020 и свойство arg со значением x.

```js
function func(x)
{
    return JSON.stringify({ love: 'javascript', year: 2020, arg: x });
}

console.log(func('hello'));
```

Comment: Все разобрался. Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Павел Если вам ответ помог, пожалуйста поставьте галочку слева от него.